# How to vectorize a string fetching script having a nested for loop?

Tags: string, r, vectorization, apply, sapply

I have a data in R as follows

```
Text <- c("reuce FR563 323 aldk", "vard 432", "DK123 fg4d", "matten global height")
ID <- c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4")
data <- data.frame(ID, Text)
data$noofwords <- sapply(data$Text, str_count,"[[:space:]]") +1
data$Text <- as.character(data$Text)
data$ID <- as.character(data$ID)


data
ID                 Text noofwords
1 S1 reuce FR563 323 aldk         4
2 S2             vard 432         2
3 S3           DK123 fg4d         2
4 S4 matten global height         3
```

I want to fetch every word in a string in Text column into a new data.frame in R along with the corresponding ID and Text field

The following script with nested for loops does the job, but is there any way to vectorise it? It is very slow for large datasets.

```
keyword <- "keyword"
text <- "text"
ID <- "ID"
Index <- data.frame(keyword,text,ID)
Index[,1:3] <- as.character(Index[,1:3])

n <- nrow(data)
for (i in 1:n) {
  k <- data[i,"noofwords"]
  kwv <- str_split(data[i,"Text"], " ", n = Inf)
  kwv <- unlist(kwv, recursive = TRUE, use.names = FALSE)
  for (j in 1:k){
    kw <- kwv[j]
    tex <- (data[i,"Text"])
    nid <- (data[i, "ID"])
    Index <- rbind(Index, c(kw,tex,nid))
  }
}


Index
   keyword                 text ID
1        1                    1  1
2    reuce reuce FR563 323 aldk S1
3    FR563 reuce FR563 323 aldk S1
4      323 reuce FR563 323 aldk S1
5     aldk reuce FR563 323 aldk S1
6     vard             vard 432 S2
7      432             vard 432 S2
8    DK123           DK123 fg4d S3
9     fg4d           DK123 fg4d S3
10  matten matten global height S4
11  global matten global height S4
12  height matten global height S4
```

Also why is there an extra first row with all 1s getting created?

Comment: The '1' appears because you coerce the values in `Index` from `factor` to `character` by `as.character`, which has the effect of creating character representations of the underlying factor code (one level for each column, so each is converted to `1`. Instead when you make index use `Index <- data.frame( keyword=character(),text=character(),id=character() )` to make an empty `data.frame`. However, I recommend my `data.table` answer. Cleaner and faster. I can add some explanation if you want?

Comment: Ok That is where the 1 comes from. The data.table solution works fine with small file, but is giving `cannot allocate vector of size 638.3 Mb` when running with 6000 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses the `data.table` package and should be relatively quick.
Do check your column types because the example data you gave gets converted to a `factor` variable (so I used `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when recreating it).

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table( data , key = "ID" )
dt[ dt[ , list( Keyword = unlist( strsplit( Text , " " ) ) ) , by = ID ] ]
#    ID                 Text Keyword
# 1: S1 reuce FR563 323 aldk   reuce
# 2: S1 reuce FR563 323 aldk   FR563
# 3: S1 reuce FR563 323 aldk     323
# 4: S1 reuce FR563 323 aldk    aldk
# 5: S2             vard 432    vard
# 6: S2             vard 432     432
# 7: S3           DK123 fg4d   DK123
# 8: S3           DK123 fg4d    fg4d
# 9: S4 matten global height  matten
#10: S4 matten global height  global
#11: S4 matten global height  height
```

Comment: works fine for small data set, but gives the following error with large data Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian) NULL else as.integer(max(nrow(x),  : 
  Join results in 18514 rows; more than 14402 = max(nrow(x),nrow(i)). Check for duplicate key values in i, each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try including `j` and dropping `by` (by-without-by) so that j runs for each group to avoid the large allocation.

Comment: `dt[ , list( Keyword = unlist( strsplit( Text , " " ) ) ) , by = list(ID, Text) ]` did the trick for me.